# i tried to create multiple sheets in excel using python openpyxl to store different values in loop, but it creates only one sheet

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried to create multiple sheets in excel using python openpyxl to store different values in loop, but it creates only one sheet.

```
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Font

table_name = ["M-1", "M-2", "M-3"]

xltitle = datetime.now()
tit_head = "ALL_MACHINE" + xltitle.strftime("%d_%m_%Y_%H_%M_%S")+".xlsx"

for tab_nam in table_name:

    filepath = tit_head

    headings = ("NAME", "ID", "EMPLOYEE NAME",
                "NUMBER", "START TIME", "STOP TIME")

    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.create_sheet()
    sheet.title = tab_nam

    sheet.row_dimensions[1].font = Font(bold=True)

    for colno, heading in enumerate(headings, start=1):
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=colno).value = heading

    wb.save(filepath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a new workbook in each iteration of the loop and then saving it, overwriting the previous one. You'll want to move the workbook creation and writing the file outside the loop. You can also move the creation of `headings` so it doesn't need to be recreated each time.

Something like this:

```
filepath = tit_head
headings = ("NAME", "ID", "EMPLOYEE NAME",
            "NUMBER", "START TIME", "STOP TIME")
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
for tab_nam in table_name:
    sheet = wb.create_sheet()
    sheet.title = tab_nam

    sheet.row_dimensions[1].font = Font(bold=True)

    for colno, heading in enumerate(headings, start=1):
        sheet.cell(row=1, column=colno).value = heading
wb.save(filepath)
```

Comment: Thank you so much